# Notifying an Observer - Getting started with Bindings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, cocoa-bindings

In order to get started with bindings, I'm writing a small application that converts temperature in Celsius to temperature in Kelvin and vice-versa.

I have two NSTextFields which are binded to two properties known as `float kelvin` and `float centigrade`. And, of course, I have two custom setters which set the value for each property appropriately.

The setter for celsius is:

```
centigrade = value;
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"kelvin"];
kelvin = value + 273;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"kelvin"];
```

I need to use `willChangeValueForKey:` otherwise the value is not updated in the other NSTextField.

My question is, is there a more elegant way to do this? If I add another property and textfield to convert the temperature to Fahrenheit, I will need to add `willChange...` and `didChange...` in that getter as well.

Is there a way to tell nib file that these two properties are linked and whenever one changes, it must notify both the observers?

EDIT:

For what its worth, I have tried calling the kelvin's setter from inside centrigrade's setter. But if I do that in the setter for kelvins as well, wouldn't it cause problems? For instance:

```
centigrade = value;
[self setKelvin:value];
```

and

```
kelvin = value;
[self setCelsius:value];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use **willChangeValueForKey:** / **didChangeValueForKey:** here, the notifications are automatic. If you are not seeing the notifications it means you are not using the properties in a [key-value coding compliant manner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE). You don't need custom setters at all.

You should only call willChangeValueForKey: / didChangeValueForKey: if you have explicitly disabled automatic kvo for those properties (there are sometimes reasons to do this, but save that for later down the line).

Once you have that working you can tackle your other problem. Yes, it is possible to have one property change trigger notifications for both properties, but as you have seen that is no use if the second property change also triggers the first again, and so on.

The problem is that your **Model** isn't sophisticated enough to deal with your problem. Forget bindings for a while, forget the presentation altogether until you have the model working. In pseudo-code, ignoring floating point details, you need to at least get something like this working:-

```
model.celcius = 100.0;
assert( model.kelvin == 373.0 )

model.kelvin = 0.0;
assert( model.celcius == -273.0 )
```

Assuming you follow the guides on kvo complience (and understand when to use it and when not to - ie, you are in control of when to trigger the notification), you will then be able to hook up your textfield bindings and everything will just work.

This might look something like:-

```
@property (assign) float *temperatureKelvin;    // only one instance variable needed

- (float)temperatureFahrenheit {
  return tempeatureKelvin * ...;                // whatever formula is
}

- (float)temperatureCelcius {
  return tempeatureKelvin * ...;                // whatever formula is
}

- (void)setTemperatureFahrenheit:(float)val {
  self.temperatureKelvin = val * ...;           // whatever formula is
}

- (void)setTemperatureCelcius:(float)val { {
  self.temperatureKelvin = val * ...;           // whatever formula is
}
```

The key to making this work is to make sure that updating the value of temperatureKelvin sends a notification that temperatureFahrenheit and temperatureCelcius have changed. You do this by registering them as dependant preoperties..

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingTemperatureFahrenheit {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"tempeatureKelvin"];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingTemperatureCelcius {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"tempeatureKelvin"];
}
```

Comment: I had a feeling I was completely off track. I am guessing I need to make my model KVO compliant and just having two float properties is not going to cut it? Furthermore, you state that I don't need custom setters at all - won't I need some code in there to convert the kelvins to celsius and vice-versa?

Comment: I also just overrode +keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey and that seems to work as well. But I'm still keen on what you said about the model. FWIW, I do have a primitive model but if I remove the custom accessors it obviously doesn't change the temperature but the values but the synthesized setters/getters are still called ofcourse and the values are updated. I have confirmed by hooking up two textfields to the same property and changing one updates the other.

Comment: i've added a bit more explanation. The point about the model is not really that you need a complex model, just that it is good to develop it independently of your views, preferably with unit tests :)

Comment: Ah, so the key is convert the values on the fly and not to store them! Thank you very much. This is great. However, the above 'keyPathsForValues...' code only updates when the key kelvin is changed. It doesn't do anything when celsius is changed. So, to do that, I had to include another set which notifies when temperatureCelsius is changed. I assume this is the correct way? For every key that affects other keys, I need to notify Cocoa by the keyPathsForValues... method.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey: is messed up - i'll correct it now